# Much memory use by .net 7 on windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-7.0

I have a problem with publishing an asp.net core MVC .net7 application on a web server with Windows server 2008 operating system. When I start the application it takes up 500 MB of RAM memory.
Thinking it was the fault of the code, I made several changes without improvements  until I tried to publish an application made with the same characteristics but empty as visual studio creates it at the beginning.
Also in this case, when the application was started, 500MB of RAM memory was taken.
Has this happened to anyone?  how can i solve?  IIS is 7.5

Comment: Have not hosted anything under IIS for quite a long time and while 500 MB seems to be a bit too much but in general I would expect the numbers not that far from that. Is the memory consumption growing inappropriately during  the app runtime under load? If not - I would not bother with it.

Comment: @GuruStron yes it increase to much up to 1,5GB

Comment: Depending on app's logic and load it can be fine.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for the answer. Also the empty application increase memory usage

Comment: The main thing you should watch out is the memory leak - [see for starters this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak). If under load memory profile is stable, GC is not heavily loaded and memory usage is acceptable based on available service resources - then I would leave it for now.

Comment: You have a bigger problem using Windows Server 2008 (R2 or not), as it reached end of life years ago. Besides, people care more about memory usage over a time internal, not just at startup. Anything below 1.5-GB is just normal. 64 bit processes allow more memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi I must use windows server 2008 unfortunately